# JQuery zebra stripe table that has groups of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I typically zebra stripe table rows for odd / even like so and it works well:

```
$("table tbody tr:visible:even",this).addClass("even"); 
$("table tbody tr:visible:odd",this).addClass("odd");
```

However, I have a data table where there are three consecutive rows for 1 set of data. The next three consecutive rows would be for the next set of data. So ideally I'd like to take the first three rows and add a class of even and then the next three rows after that to have a class of odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvmf9/) something I whipped up on jsfiddle:

```
$("tr:nth-child(6n)").addClass("odd")
    .prev().addClass("odd")
    .prev().addClass("odd");
```

What this does is select every 6th `tr` element, set its class to `odd`, and the same to the previous two `tr` elements, thus giving you the result of 3 "grouped" rows.

More about the [`nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector here, and more about the [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function here.

You could change the code to this to add an `even` class to the three rows preceding the ones with the `odd` classname:

```
$("tr:nth-child(6n)").addClass("odd")
    .prev().addClass("odd")
    .prev().addClass("odd")
    .prev().addClass("even")
    .prev().addClass("even")
    .prev().addClass("even");
```

That looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qvmf9/1/).

Comment: I like this, was looking for something without using .each myself

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that can work with more complex formulas.

http://jsfiddle.net/JRPmw/

You use jQuery's filter instead. You provide as complex an equation as you like and return true for rows you want.

```
$('tr').filter( function(n) {
    var x = (n+1) % 6;
    if (x >= 1 && x <= 3) return true;
}).addClass('threes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector :

```
$("table tbody tr:visible:nth-child(6n+1)").addClass("even");
$("table tbody tr:visible:nth-child(6n+2)").addClass("even");
$("table tbody tr:visible:nth-child(6n+3)").addClass("even");
$("table tbody tr:visible:nth-child(6n+4)").addClass("odd");
$("table tbody tr:visible:nth-child(6n+5)").addClass("odd");
$("table tbody tr:visible:nth-child(6n+6)").addClass("odd");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/5Xnvu/