# Pass variable and DOM element to jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling with this for a while, and have tried many searches, but haven't found the right solution, nor words for the issue I have.
I wish to traverse the `<tr>`'s in `<table id="Listeners">` with jQuery, and set the rows to either Even or Odd class.

The  is yet saved in a variable and passed to the function, as follows:

```
<table id="Listeners">
 <tr><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

And my jQuery:

```
var Element = $("#Listeners");
$(Element+" tr").each(function(index) {
 if (index%2 == 0) {
  $(this).addClass("Even");
 }
});
```

But that doesn't work, any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: I think you want (maybe?) `$('selector', Element)...`?

Comment: What about replacing the whole block with `$('#listeners > tbody > tr').filter(':even').addClass('even');`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery zebra stripe table that has groups of rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145719/jquery-zebra-stripe-table-that-has-groups-of-rows)

Comment: Jared's solution:
`$("tr", Element).each(function(index) {
 alert(index);
});`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find()` method and **[`:even`](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)** selector:

> Selects even elements, zero-indexed.

```
var $element = $("#Listeners");
$element.find("tr:even").addClass("Even");
// or $element.find("tr").filter(':even').addClass("Even")
```

Comment: Excellent!
`Element.find("tr:even").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");`

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. This should work:

```
$('#Listeners tr:nth-child(even)').addClass("Even");
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Even this:

```
$('#Listeners tr:even').addClass("Even");
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/zm2nN/